# Configuring the date parser when using pandas.PeriodIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dates in this format:

```
>>> dates = ["01/01/2000", "02/01/2000", "25/01/2000", "01/01/3005"]
```

I'd like to create a `pandas.PeriodIndex` from these dates. Note however that these dates are in British format, not American, so "02/01/2000" is the 2nd Jan, not the 1st Feb. The default behaviour of `pandas.PeriodIndex` doesn't work:

```
>>> pandas.PeriodIndex(dates, freq="D")
PeriodIndex(['2000-01-01', '2000-02-01', '2000-01-25', '3005-01-01'], dtype='period[D]', freq='D')
```

Other functions in pandas accept a "day first" argument which handles this situation. How can I work around this?

Edit: I should mention also that I'm using Period rather than Timestamp as I need to work with dates outside of the Timestamp valid range.

Comment: What do you expect to do for those invalid dates?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `format` string to create a `DatetimeIndex` this has the method to [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period) to convert to a `PeriodIndex` for you:

```
In [63]:
dates = ["01/01/2000", "02/01/2000", "25/01/2000"]
pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%d/%m/%Y').to_period(freq='D')

Out[63]:
PeriodIndex(['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-25'], dtype='period[D]', freq='D')
```

You can also just pass `dayFirst=True`:

```
In [64]:
dates = ["01/01/2000", "02/01/2000", "25/01/2000"]
pd.to_datetime(dates, dayfirst=True).to_period(freq='D')

Out[64]:
PeriodIndex(['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-25'], dtype='period[D]', freq='D')
```

**Update**

for invalid dates you can split the string dates and convert to `int` and then pass these as args to `PeriodIndex` ctor:

```
In [67]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates})
df

Out[67]:
        dates
0  01/01/2000
1  02/01/2000
2  25/01/2000
3  01/01/3005

In [72]:
df[['day','month','year']] = df['dates'].str.split('/', expand=True).astype(int)
df

Out[72]:
        dates  day  month  year
0  01/01/2000    1      1  2000
1  02/01/2000    2      1  2000
2  25/01/2000   25      1  2000
3  01/01/3005    1      1  3005


In [75]:
df['period'] = pd.PeriodIndex(day = df['day'], month=df['month'], year = df['year'], freq='D')
df

Out[75]:
        dates  day  month  year     period
0  01/01/2000    1      1  2000 2000-01-01
1  02/01/2000    2      1  2000 2000-01-02
2  25/01/2000   25      1  2000 2000-01-25
3  01/01/3005    1      1  3005 3005-01-01
```

You can see that this produces the desired result:

```
In [77]:
pd.PeriodIndex(day = df['day'], month=df['month'], year = df['year'], freq='D')

Out[77]:
PeriodIndex(['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-25', '3005-01-01'], dtype='period[D]', freq='D')
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed from the original post that I need to use Period not Timestamp as some of my dates are outside the valid range (e.g. "01/02/3000"), at which point to_datetime falls over with pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime.